# Prevent script from overriding page title in Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, html, joomla, title, reset

I'm working on a project that is built on Joomla 1.5. I've been trying to set the title of the pages for different views and everything works fine except for that title of the document is set to as the project name once the document is loaded completely. However, I can clearly see the title set by me as the document title while it is loading. Also, when I checked in firebug, I found that some script is overwriting document title over and over again on a span of 2 sec. I checked almost all the settings pages to disable this but couldn't find any such option; I'm not a Joomla expert. Also, I don't want to delete that script manually, so if someone has any idea about how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it.
PS: I searched for solution before posting this so please, no -1.

Comment: Which script is causing the problem? A core Joomla script or one coming from a 3rd party extension?

Comment: Joomla one. Anyways, I got the answer. Will post that in answer in a minute.

Comment: Hey. The answer I posted didn't work. Could you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, there was a script in a file `chat.js` on our server that was updating the page title every 2 seconds. So lame that I didn't realize it could be such a minor mistake. I wasn't able to find it as it was being included only in some views. Anyways, sorry for wasting your times. If anyone of you've faced a similar issue, please do check your script in Javascript `debugger`.